# Access with a pointer on two structures with an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I got another issue with my Code. I want to access on all 3 values with a simple pointer usage. But my Pointer jumps too far.
My Output is this:

1. Value is 1
2. Value is 4194432
3. Value is 2686824

I guess that my Problem is, that my pointer is from the wrong type. So pointer++ dont jump to the next array element. I really dont know, how i can solve this.
(It's only a simple example to reproduce my problem, so dont look for sense in doing this)

```
typedef struct _A {
int value;
}A;

typedef struct _B {
A array[10];
}B;

int main()
{
    A atest;
    B btest;
    B *p=NULL;

    btest.array[0].value=1;
    btest.array[1].value=3;
    btest.array[2].value=5;

    p=malloc(10 * sizeof(btest));
    p=&btest.array;
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d. Value is %d\n",i+1,p++->array->value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thx for reading and if something is missing in my explanation, then i will apologize and add it.

EDIT:

Additionally to Some Programmers Dude Sollution, i add a simple cast mechanic:

```
    q=(A*) p;
    q++;
    p =(B*)q;
```

Thx for your help :)

Comment: Names starting with undewrscore are reserved for the implementation at file scope for all name spaces! And names like `A` are a no-go anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines

```
p=malloc(10 * sizeof(btest));
p=&btest.array;
```

contains *two* problems. The first is that with the second assignment you *lose* the memory you allocated. It does not copy the contents of `btest.array`.

The second problem is that `p` is a pointer to `B` but `&btest.array` is a pointer to an array of ten `A` elements (its type is `A (*)[10]`). Those two are *very* different types.

If you want to copy `btest` into the memory allocated for `p` (which is a pointer to *ten* `B` structures which is a little overkill) do e.g.

```
p=malloc(sizeof *p);
memcpy(p, &btest, sizeof *p);
```

Then to the *next* problem:

```
p++->array->value
```

The `p++` will make `p` point to the *next* element in the array pointed to by `p`, but that's wrong. You should loop over `p->array` instead like

```
p->array[i].value
```

Comment: Thx for your help and explanation work, Some programmer dude. Even with your improvements, my results are wrong. I know, that my array has the type of A, but i was irritated because it points to B. I try to use a cast before its incremented and cast back after it.

Comment: With your Improvings and a little cast my problem was solved :)  thx Some programmer dude!